# multiple values from cookie to var in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, cookies

My code looks like:

```
  var ietms = $cookies.get('items');
```

I can get values back, however there are multiples such as:

```
Testvalue1|Testvalue2|testvalue3
```

I want to be able to split the three items lets say into multiple vars, like:

```
var ietms = $cookies.get('items')[0];
var ietms2 = $cookies.get('items')[1];
var ietms3 = $cookies.get('items')[2];
```

But simply split the value based on the '|' separating the values

Answer (score 0):

If the returned data is a string, you can use `var splitItems = ietms.split('|')` to create one array consisting of the individual values. But its hard to say if this applies to your question, because the return type of testvalue1|..|.. is unclear